# CSS Space Appearing

Tags: css

I am trying to make a simple responsive html page and I have a little problem.

I have two divs that I want to display inline.

When the width is lower than X, I will hide the 2nd div.

This works okay for me.

But when I add some content that is longer than the width, the word-wrap comes in action and some white space appears at the top of the first div.

I will post the code.

I want to remove that white space at the top( the divs to remain inline )

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').click(function(e) {  
  if( $('#menu').text() == "SHOW INFO" )
   $('#menu').text('HIDE INFO');
  else
   $('#menu').text('SHOW INFO');
    });
});
```

```css
html, body 
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper
{
 background-color:white;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.menu { display:none; }

.content
{
 color:yellow;
 background-color:black;
 width:70%;
 height:100%;
 display: inline-block;
}

.info
{
 background-color:white;
 width:29%;
 height:100%;
 display: inline-block;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 700px) 
{ 
 .content
 {
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }

 .info { display:none; }
 
 .menu
 {
  display:block;
  height:40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #D00355;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;     
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        transition: background 0.5s linear;
 }
 
 .menu:hover
 {
  background-color:#D00355;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
        transition: background 0.5s linear;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Responsive Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content">
  1
 </div>
 <div class="info">
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 </div>
 
 <div class="menu" id="menu" name="menu">SHOW INFO</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use `<p>` instead of `<br>`?

Comment: i don't want to use <p>, because the problem appears also at the word-wrap:break-word;

Comment: i'll let you complete your questions and finish editing before I answer again... seems you are still trying to figure out what to ask. take your time as clarity helps all of us

Comment: now i completed the code. word-wrap:break-word; or '<br>' make a white space appear at the top as you can see.

Answer (score 2):

This style will prevent the extra top spacing for the first div:

```
.wrapper > div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here's a good article that compares `inline-block` to `float` styles, and it addresses the need for adding `vertical-align: top`:  http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

**Snippet**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: black;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info {
  background-color: white;
  width: 29%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.infobox {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="infobox">asdadasdadas
      <br>asdadsa
      <br>asdadsa
      <br>asdadsa
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu" id="menu" name="menu">SHOW INFO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey add a `float` property for your elements:

```
.content, .info {
    float:left;
}
```